# Duvida Css - Unificar Divs

Tags: php, css, html5, css3

Olá Pessoal Boa tarde!

vejam a imagem abaixo, existe alguma propriedade css na qual eu consiga remover a linha de divisão das 2 divs para o conteúdo ficar igual? ou a melhor opção seria obter uma imagem já no formato que eu desejo ?  Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Css

```
nav.navbar.navbar-inverse{
    position: fixed;       
    height: 45px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);       
    left: 24%;
    width: 100%;
    border:none;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-9.5deg); /* Chrome, Opera */
    -ms-transform: skew(-9.5deg); /* IE */
    transform: skew(-9.5deg); /* Padrão */
    z-index: 804;      
}


.logo-topo{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);   
    float:left;
    height: 165px;
    left: -3%;
    width: 380px;


    -webkit-transform: skew(-10.0deg); /* Chrome, Opera */
    -ms-transform: skew(-10.0deg); /* IE */
    transform: skew(-10.0deg); /* Padrão */
    z-index: 805;  
    border:none;
    border-radius: none;   


}
```

**HTML**

**Menu**

```
      <!-- Menu do Site -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <?php 
                // verificando se existe um diretorio raiz cadastrado para fins de desenvolvimento (configuration.php)
                $dir = diretorio();
              ?>
                <li><a href=<?=(Empty($dir))? URL::getBase()."/home/home": URL::getBase()."/".$dir."/home/home"?>><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Home</a></li>
                <li><a href=<?=(Empty($dir))? URL::getBase()."/home/home#seguros": URL::getBase()."/".$dir."/home/home#seguros" ?>><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li><a href=<?=(Empty($dir))? URL::getBase()."/home/home#seguradora": URL::getBase()."/".$dir."/home/home#seguradora"?>><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href=<?=(Empty($dir))? URL::getBase()."/home/noticias": URL::getBase()."/".$dir."/home/noticias"?>><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Noticias</a></li>
                <li><a href=<?=(Empty($dir))? URL::getBase()."/home/home#faleconosco": URL::getBase()."/".$dir."/home/home#faleconosco"?>><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Contato</a></li>
             </ul>

           </div>
        </nav>
```

**Logo**

```
<!-- classe para centralizar -->
<div class="container">
    <div class = "logo-topo">
      <!-- imagem do logo -->
        <?php
          foreach($result_logo as $dados_logo){
          echo"<a href='index.php'><img id='logo' src='$dados_logo->caminho_logo' alt='LogoTipo' width= '250'></a>";
          }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: E o codigo HTML?

Comment: adicionado! obrigado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a solução seria separa-las e determinar o tamanho e posicionamento diferentes  (utilize fundo transparente em PNG). Posso estar enganado, mas não encontrei nenhuma irregularidade em seu código.

Comment: galera segui a linha de raciocínio dessa postagem, coloquei um fundo branco no formato que precisava, adicionei transparência e assim o problema foi resolvido. obrigado!